# Can I include NSError** as a parameter in init in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

My iOS Application fetches a JSON from a REST service. The JSON contains a status code and data. 
If the code is 200, the data is the requested object otherwise the data is an error description.

The  JSON can be used to build several kinds of objects so I've made a factory class that takes the json data in its constructor and the instance methods parse the data into different objects as necessary.

My question is, is it okay to include NSError** as a parameter in the constructor in case the status code is not 200. The method header would look something like this:

```
-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *) json error: (NSError **) error;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is perfectly OK syntactically, the approach would be questionable in terms of functionality.

The problem is that when the invocation of the initializer is unsuccessful and `nil` is returned, the space for the object is still allocated (and then promptly deallocated), because you have no control over it. The call of `alloc` in

```
MyObj *obj = [[MyObj alloc] initWithData:data error:&err];
```

happens outside of your code.

You would be better off hiding the initializer from the caller, and exposing a class "factory" method, like this:

```
+(instancetype) myclassWithData:(NSData *) json error: (NSError **) error;
```

This way you can decide when to call `alloc`, so there would be no useless memory allocation / deallocation when you know for sure that there is no object to create.

Comment: I assumed he still needed the object anyway, since he didn't mention returning nil but yes, this makes sense...

Comment: That is wrong. You'd have an NSError* somewhere in the caller, just as with any other method that uses an NSError**. It's unusual, and I've never actually seen it done, but there's no reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: @gnasher729 Please point to a place in my answer where I said that it wouldn't work or that it is wrong (hint: I didn't). It is usually a good idea to **read** the answer before writing a negative comment.

Comment: You said that there is a problem. 1. This is no problem. 2. It does not depend on an out parameter. I agree that a "factory" is the better approach, but a convenience allocator isn't better, because it potentially returns an autoreleased object that lives potentially very much longer. If you want to use a "factory" method in nowadays, you should use a `new` allocator.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I said that there is a problem with allocating and promptly deallocating space in case when there is an error, and that problem is clearly there.

Comment: There is still no problem. (Many initializers can return `nil`.) But, and that is the important fact, if there is a problem with it, it has nothing to do with the out parameter.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Of course initializer can and will return `nil`. I am talking about the result of `[MyClass alloc]`, which would be allocated and released, instead of not being allocated in the first place.

Comment: And you have this behavior for every initializers that can return `nil`. This is no problem.

Comment: Thanks! This is the approach I went with in the end

Comment: Typically, a factory method is a wrapper for a call to `alloc` followed by a call to a corresponding `init`... method, i.e., an initializer with a similar name and identical arguments. Failing to provide an appropriate initializer method could potentially give rise to problems in correctly designing subclasses.

Comment: In my case when I used the
-(instancetype) initWithData:(NSData *) json error: (NSError **) error;
design static analyzer was complaining that object (error) is autoreleased too many times. So I ended up using:
+(instancetype) myclassWithData:(NSData *) json error: (NSError **) error;
to silence the static analyzer’s warning.
@dasblinkenlight: any idea what went wrong?

Comment: @Raunak I suspect that this has something to do with naming conventions and the way the ARC compiler figures out what's autoreleased. You may want to ask this as a stand-alone question, because it seems like it has wide applicability.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it might be unusual as I don't recall any iOS APIs that does it in init, but it's not wrong...

Comment: Here's a fairly well-known example: `-[NSString initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]`

Comment: I wonder if `NSString` is able to use this approach because it's a [class cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)?

Answer (score 1):

It's okay. I did that many times. Take into account that in Objective-C object construction is no language feature, but a part of the framework. Therefore initializers are no special methods. The only special case with initializers is that they consume `self` and transfer the ownership of the return value. But this has nothing to do with out parameters.

It is unusual, because an initializer typically cannot break. So usually you simply do not need it.